# How can I have the BottomNavigationBar respond to navigation to a new page via AlertDialog?

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, bottomnavigationview

I have a `navigation_bar.dart` file that handles changing to new pages within my app. Within it, I am using the `bottomNavigationBar` to build out four different pages based on what tab is currently selected like so:

```dart
class NavigationBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NavigationBarState createState() => _NavigationBarState();
}

class _NavigationBarState extends State<NavigationBar> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  final List<Widget> _pageOptions = <Widget>[
    Page1(),
    Page2(),
    Page3(),
    Page4(),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String userID =
        Provider.of<FirebaseUser>(context, listen: false) != null ? Provider.of<FirebaseUser>(context).uid : 'null';

    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [StreamProvider<MyUser>.value(value: DatabaseService().streamUser(userID))],
      child: Scaffold(
        body: IndexedStack(
          children: _pageOptions,
          index: _selectedIndex,
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: Theme(
          data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
            canvasColor: Color(0xff271037).withOpacity(0.90),
            splashColor: Colors.transparent,
          ),
          child: BottomNavigationBar(
            currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
            onTap: _onItemTapped,
            unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
            selectedItemColor: Color(0xff3ADEA7),
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
            items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Container(),
                title: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.fire, color: Colors.white),
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Container(),
                title: Icon(Icons.fastfood, color: Colors.white),
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Container(),
                title: Icon(Icons.directions_bike, color: Colors.white),
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Container(),
                title: Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.white),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now, in a different file which is `Page3.dart`, on that page there is an alert dialog that pops up and when clicked, I want it to navigate to Page4().

```dart
Future<void> _showMissingDataDialog(String data) async {
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('You have not set your $data yet.'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              splashColor: Colors.transparent,
              highlightColor: Colors.grey[200],
              textColor: Colors.black,
              child: const Text('Cancel'),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
            ),
            FlatButton(
                splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                highlightColor: Colors.grey[200],
                textColor: Colors.black,
                child: Text('Set $data', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  // TODO: Redirect to page4() here as if it was tapped on the BottomNavigationBar
                })
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

How can I have it so that clicking the "Set $data" button would route to Page4()? I want to make it so that the `bottomNavigationBar` reacts to this as if you tapped on the actual fourth `BottomNavigationBarItem` item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give your Nav Bar a Global Key. I declared this outside of all widgets on my main Dart file.

```
GlobalKey navBarGlobalKey = GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'bottomAppBar');

bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        key: navBarGlobalKey,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        items: [ ... ]
```

Then use the global key to call the onTap Method in the onPressed method of your button. You will have to import the other dart file into this page before the global key is available.

```
final BottomNavigationBar navigationBar = navBarGlobalKey.currentWidget;
              initialIndex = 0;
              navigationBar.onTap(3); //Starts at index 0, so passing in 3 should do the trick.
```

Comment: Thank you, this is solution is much simpler than mine and exactly what I wanted.

Comment: This approach is absolutely superb. Succinct, clean and simple. No need for anything like Provider or Bloc if you just want another way of accessing a page on the nav bar from a button press.

Comment: can you explain to me why do we need a global key for this solution?

Comment: @Vince The global key allows you to access the BottomNavigationBar from another Widget in the Scaffold without the pain of trying to pass data back and forth from widgets that are deeply nested.